# Package functions on strings using GPU in Python - Generating addresses from private keys

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, cryptography, gpu

Problem: I am trying to convert a very big list (many millions) of private keys (hexadecimal format, stored in a list of strings) to addresses. Can this be run on the GPU?

I have tried looking for resources on how to adapt my code to a GPU/CUDA-friendly version. However, I've found that most examples online are for pure math operations on a list of ints or floats. Also, the function where the 'processing' is defined is also entirely re-written, and does not use functions from packages (other than those already supported by numpy etc.).

Is there a way to make the [private key -> public key -> address] process GPU-friendly, and can string operations be carried out on a GPU in the first place?

The following is what I have for my serial CPU version for Python3.x:

```
import codecs
import hashlib
import ecdsa

def get_pub_keys(priv_key):

    private_hex = codecs.decode(priv_key, 'hex')

    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_hex, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).verifying_key
    key_bytes = key.to_string()
    key_hex = codecs.encode(key_bytes, 'hex')

    public_key_uncompressed = b'04' + key_hex

    key_string = key_hex.decode('utf-8')
    last_byte = int(key_string[-1], 16)

    half_len = len(key_hex) // 2
    key_half = key_hex[:half_len]

    bitcoin_byte = b'02' if last_byte % 2 == 0 else b'03'
    public_key_compressed = bitcoin_byte + key_half

    return public_key_uncompressed, public_key_compressed    

def public_to_address(public_key):
    public_key_bytes = codecs.decode(public_key, 'hex')
    # Run SHA256 for the public key
    sha256_bpk = hashlib.sha256(public_key_bytes)
    sha256_bpk_digest = sha256_bpk.digest()
    # Run ripemd160 for the SHA256
    ripemd160_bpk = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    ripemd160_bpk.update(sha256_bpk_digest)
    ripemd160_bpk_digest = ripemd160_bpk.digest()
    ripemd160_bpk_hex = codecs.encode(ripemd160_bpk_digest, 'hex')
    # Add network byte
    network_byte = b'00'
    network_bitcoin_public_key = network_byte + ripemd160_bpk_hex
    network_bitcoin_public_key_bytes = codecs.decode(network_bitcoin_public_key, 'hex')
    # Double SHA256 to get checksum
    sha256_nbpk = hashlib.sha256(network_bitcoin_public_key_bytes)
    sha256_nbpk_digest = sha256_nbpk.digest()
    sha256_2_nbpk = hashlib.sha256(sha256_nbpk_digest)
    sha256_2_nbpk_digest = sha256_2_nbpk.digest()
    sha256_2_hex = codecs.encode(sha256_2_nbpk_digest, 'hex')
    checksum = sha256_2_hex[:8]
    # Concatenate public key and checksum to get the address
    address_hex = (network_bitcoin_public_key + checksum).decode('utf-8')
    wallet = base58(address_hex)
    return wallet

def base58(address_hex):
    alphabet = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    b58_string = ''
    # Get the number of leading zeros and convert hex to decimal
    leading_zeros = len(address_hex) - len(address_hex.lstrip('0'))
    # Convert hex to decimal
    address_int = int(address_hex, 16)
    # Append digits to the start of string
    while address_int > 0:
        digit = address_int % 58
        digit_char = alphabet[digit]
        b58_string = digit_char + b58_string
        address_int //= 58
    # Add '1' for each 2 leading zeros
    ones = leading_zeros // 2
    for one in range(ones):
        b58_string = '1' + b58_string
    return b58_string


def get_addresses(i):

    key1,key2 = get_pub_keys(i)
    add1 = public_to_address(key1)
    add2 = public_to_address(key2)

    return add1, add2


filename = 'bunchOfHexKeys.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    hexKeys = f.read().splitlines()

addresses = []

for i in hexKeys:
    addresses.append(get_addresses(i))
```

As can be seen, I'm using many functions from the 3 imported packages. So far the only way I can see is to rewrite those. Is there another way?

The size of hexKeys isn't an issue for the GPU cache size, as I can just adjust the input list as needed.

Comment: I don't see any advantage to repeatedly cycling between the `bytes` objects and hex string objects. Just keep everything as a `bytes` object until the very end when you convert to a base58 string. I would expect the time to be dominated by either the two hashes or the elliptic curve scalar multiplication that happens under the hood to obtain your public key from your private key.

Comment: Yeah youre right. Most of the execution time is taken by the elliptic curve function. Ill see if I can implement that in C

Comment: The [documenation](https://pypi.org/project/ecdsa/) for the package states that: *In case higher performance is wanted and using native code is not a problem, it's possible to specify installation together with* `gmpy2`: `pip install ecdsa[gmpy2]` That will get the most compute intensive part of the code in very well optimized native library called `gmp`.